# handleChange event Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to implement search bar but it seems it doesn't work.

```
const [dataCoupons, setDataCoupons] = useState<Coupon[] | undefined>(coupons);

const handleChange = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement> & { length: number }) => {
  let couponsFilter = dataCoupons;

  if (e.length > 0) {
    Object.keys(e).forEach((k) => {
      if (e[k].value === 0) {
        couponsFilter = couponsFilter
          ?.slice()
          .filter((x) => x.durationType.localeCompare('ONCE') === 0);
      }
      if (e[k].value === 3) {
        couponsFilter = couponsFilter?.slice().filter((x) => x.valid === true);
      }
      if (e[k].value === 4) {
        couponsFilter = couponsFilter?.slice().filter((x) => x.valid === false);
      }
    });
  } else {
    couponsFilter = coupons;
  }
  setDataCoupons(couponsFilter);
};
```

```
<Select
   onChange={handleChange}
   isMulti
   options={options}
   isClearable={isClearable}
   classNamePrefix='select'
/>
```

I have an error message for each e[k]

[image]

What am i missing ?

Comment: with events to get the value, you need to use `e.target.value` or `e.currentTarget.value` try to see what keys you are getting in `k`

Answer (score 0):

There are two main things stopping you from getting `value`.

1. You're protecting with `if (e.length > 0) {}`

`e` does not normally have `length` property because it is an object. If you watched closely, TypeScript does tell you that. It is why you had to add `& { length: number }` to stop TypeScript from complaining.

[image]

2. If you were to do something like below (without the above mentioned protection)

```
Object.keys(e).forEach((k) => { console.log(k) })
```

And then went and triggered change event, you would be able to observe that the console is printing out string keys of all the properties that are attached to `e` object directly.

One of those properties is `target` property. You are most likely after that property. Going along the lines of your thinking (how you wrote your code), you would most likely need something like below:

```
Object.keys(e).forEach((k) => {
  if (k === "target") {
    console.log(e[k].value);
  }
});
```

The above will capture value from the input field.

I have to warn you though that it seems like a very unsustainable way of creating forms and getting their values. It would be probably best to read [this](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html) before you proceed.

Also, here's [Sandbox to see it in action](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-frost-0jyzq?file=/src/App.tsx) in most simple implementation.